# how to get file mime Type while uploading file with ionic 3 app?

Tags: file, pdf, ionic-framework, ionic3, mime-types

I am getting an error while upload any file type with ionic 3 app, can you help me to check file type to set their file extension.

Thanks
Vikas

Comment: And what is that error?

Comment: I used fileChoose method to browse files in device. below is my complete code:

this.fileChooser.open()
      .then(uri => {
        console.log("My File URI" + uri) // i got file name without file extension here... 
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

        let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
          fileKey: 'attachment',
          fileName: 'attachment',
          chunkedMode: false

        }

Comment: is there any way to get file extensions?

Comment: And what is your error?

Comment: there is no error, i just want to get file extension, when  i used above code then instead of complete file i.e "file1.jpeg" i got only "file1"

I want extract file type once file have been chosen.

Comment: Apologies, I assumed that there was an error because your question starts with "I am getting an error".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with ionic 3. When you add a new tag in the index, for example, you must add the type content in the tag.For example:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="assets/js/lalalala.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
```

Then, you need restart the server (whit ionic serve), because the error persist.

Also, you can know the type of your called in the browser inspector.At the network tab.